# Confusion with printf command?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have to print the following three lines in one print command without using echo command. So I have chosen printf command.Here are the three lines:

```
  Different characters can be represented and supported 
  in the print command, for example: 
  x-y, X+Y, –, +, <, >, %, $, #, &.
```

What I have done so far is:

```
   printf "
   Different characters can be represented and supported 
   in the print command, for example: 
   x-y, X+Y, –, +, <, >, %, $, #, &.
   "
```

But I got bash error for the third line ','.

So will anyone enlighten me up.

Comment: By the way, there's a difference between the `print` command the `printf` command.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Better to use:

```
printf "Different characters can be represented and supported\n\
in the print command, for example:\n\
x-y, X+Y, –, +, <, >, %%, $, #, &.\n"
```

You get that error, as others have said here, because of `%` character which is special and must to be escaped.

See [`man 1 printf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/printf.1posix.html) for more info.

Comment: @Narwen I sugest you to use the man all the time when you have to play with special characters. To search in man, type `/your_string_to_search` and then press enter.

Comment: The whole point of `printf` is that `%` character and what it does!

Answer (score 15):

`%` is a special character in `printf`. That's what's causing the error. You need to escape it as `%%`.

`$` may also be substituted when within double quotes by the outer shell, so you should to escape that (`\$`). It is usually just easier to use single quotes.

Comment: The dollar sign is only special when it is followed by a valid variable name which is not the case here.

Comment: `$variable` is replaced by the shell, not by `printf`. If you surround your string with single quotes instead of double quotes, `$` will no be interpolated by the shell and will get passed directly to `printf`.

Comment: @glennjackman Besides being special when followed by a valid variable name (whether or not that variable is actually defined), `$` is also special [when followed by `{`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) or by a [special parameter symbol](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters), or [one or more digits](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html#Positional-Parameters). The basic idea of what you are saying is correct, though.

Answer (score 10):

the <kbd>%</kbd> is special for printf: it is the leading char in format specifiers. If you want a literal percent, use `%%`

Answer (score 10):

It is a bit surprising to see that when you are not allowed to use the `echo` command that you chose to use the `printf` command instead.

Why not `cat` ?

```
#!/bin/bash

cat<<'EOF'
Different characters can be represented and supported
in the print command, for example:
x-y, X+Y, –, +, <, >, %, $, #, &.
EOF
```

Comment: But I had to replace echo with print command according to question. But thanks for the help.

Comment: To avoid interpreting strings like `$foo` in the text, use `cat <<'EOF'` instead of `cat <<EOF`.

Answer (score 4):

`printf` is a formatted print which takes a format string as its first parameter. The rest of the parameters are used in the format string. The three things to remember when using `printf` are:

1. Although many languages have `printf` statements/commands/functions, they all differ a bit so always verify details in language specific documentation (C, bash, php, perl, etc.),
2. You should never use user supplied information in the format string. This is always a security flaw. If you want to display a user supplied string use a format string like `"%s"`.
3. Both the backslash (`\`) and the percent sign (`%`) are escape characters which change the meaning of the following character(s) if you want an escape character to appear in your output, it must be escaped or pulled in from another parameter. The dollar sign (`$`) is not special to printf, but is special to the shell, so be careful of your quotes.

`printf` is great for formatting numbers. look at the man pages for details

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, the `%` symbol is special for `printf`.

If you just want to print out a string as it is, give to `printf` `%s` as a first argument, and the string surrounded in single quotes as the second argument:

```
printf %s '
Different characters can be represented and supported 
in the printf command, for example: 
x-y, X+Y, –, +, <, >, %, $, #, &.
'
```

Using single quotes instead of double quotes stops the shell from interpolating symbols like `$`.